# Kali mirror sync error on laptop, desktop, bootable usb, and Raspberry Pi 4B 8gb

Tags: linux, sync, updates, kali-linux, mirroring

I have a problem with Kali Linux. I am currently running Kali on my laptop, desktop, Raspberry Pi 4B 8gb, and a bootable usb with 256gb storage. I recently tried updating, but all independent devices give a mirror sync error. Depending on running "sudo apt update" or "sudo apt-get update" I seem to get errors with different mirrors. I even took my bootable usb to work and tried it there, but same issue.

Could anyone maybe shine some light on the origin of this problem for me? Thanks for the help in advance.

```
┌──(kali㉿kali-raspberry-pi)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.6 kB]
Hit:2 http://http.re4son-kernel.com/re4son kali-pi InRelease
Get:3 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Packages [18.0 MB]
Get:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb) [41.1 MB]
Get:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb) [41.1 MB]
Get:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb) [41.1 MB]
Get:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb) [41.1 MB]
Get:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb) [41.1 MB]
Ign:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb)
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb)
  File has unexpected size (41176142 != 41123139). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 145.220.21.40 80]
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb)
  File has unexpected size (41176142 != 41123139). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 145.220.21.40 80]
Fetched 30.6 kB in 4s (7,471 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/Contents-arm64  File has unexpected size (41176142 != 41123139). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 145.220.21.40 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
                                                                                                             
┌──(kali㉿kali-raspberry-pi)-[~]
└─$


┌──(kali㉿kali-raspberry-pi)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt-get update                
Get:1 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.6 kB]
Hit:2 http://http.re4son-kernel.com/re4son kali-pi InRelease
Get:3 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Packages [18.0 MB]
Get:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb) [41.1 MB]
Get:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb) [41.1 MB]
Get:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb) [41.1 MB]
Get:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb) [41.1 MB]
Get:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb) [41.1 MB]
Ign:4 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb)
Get:4 http://ftp2.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb) [41.1 MB]
Err:4 http://ftp2.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Contents (deb)
  File has unexpected size (41176142 != 41123139). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 145.220.21.40 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:41123139 [weak]
   - SHA256:041d12ee243d886a7c9b4a8332c19c52b34fe5cfbe9d6a8ef10a4d7def2a9878
   - SHA1:e000dcf1bd183adc30d8399ada2c809d1016f72f [weak]
   - MD5Sum:8f2ff447fbae65a1c5b08b260ec03f04 [weak]
  Release file created at: Thu, 07 Apr 2022 18:04:49 +0000
Fetched 30.6 kB in 4s (6,876 B/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp2.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/Contents-arm64.gz  File has unexpected size (41176142 != 41123139). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 145.220.21.40 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:41123139 [weak]
    - SHA256:041d12ee243d886a7c9b4a8332c19c52b34fe5cfbe9d6a8ef10a4d7def2a9878
    - SHA1:e000dcf1bd183adc30d8399ada2c809d1016f72f [weak]
    - MD5Sum:8f2ff447fbae65a1c5b08b260ec03f04 [weak]
   Release file created at: Thu, 07 Apr 2022 18:04:49 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
                                                                                                             
┌──(kali㉿kali-raspberry-pi)-[~]
└─$
```

Comment: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
 often works for me with Kali

Comment: Unfortunately not for me. Still get the same error

Comment: Make sure you are using Kali Bare Metal and not portable on a PC.  You may need to reinstall Kali.

Comment: I am using bare metal on both pc and laptop. for rpi4 im running kali-linux-2022.1-raspberry-pi-arm64.img.xz, and on usb im running live boot 2022.1 point release

Answer (score 1):

Use/set a different mirror in apt/sources.list ( check mirror lists on kali.org ).
Unfortunately I often experience these mismatches on ... nluug.nl ... Kali mirror

Comment: I have tried a few different mirrors. Could you maybe let me know which mirrors you are using? That would be greatly appreciated.